# iterate over imported react components

Tags: reactjs, import, jestjs

How could we iterate on imported list of react components ? :(
I tried to do it like this but does not work

```
import * as Stories from "./test.stories";

const stories = Object.keys(Stories);
<div>
  {stories.map(s => {
    const S = Stories[s];
     return <S />
    })}
</div>
```

When I do this Jest will tell me :
"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."
I am using jest since I am trying to do that for testing. (Trying to creat manually a test for each story imported from stroybook file)

Comment: How are you exporting from `test.stories`?

Comment: in this file (test.strories.tsx), there is many like this :
export const A = ...  //
export const B = ...  // 
export const C = ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is because the 'default' export from Stories is an object, which is included in `Stories` from your `import * as Stories`. An object can't be rendered. Whereas the stories you're looking to import are functions, which can be rendered with `<S />` as you have.

So a quick solution would be to filter out non-functions.

```
if ( typeof Story !== 'function' ) {
  return null;
}
return <S />;
```

That being said, I don't know if that's a proper solution to what you're actually looking to do. Just that it should "work".